# Is this definition of a modulation operator ambiguous?

Tags: operator-theory

For $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$, define a modulation operator $E_b$ from $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ to itself as:

$E_b f(x) = e^{2\pi i b x}f(x)$ .

Then the question is: for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, what is $E_bf(x-a)$?

I don't know if this is standard notation or not because I'm a beginner, but this is how the operator is defined in a book I am reading. However, it seems to me that the definition allows this question to be answered in two ways.

First, let $y = x-a$ . Then

$E_bf(x-a) = E_bf(y) = e^{2\pi i b y}f(y) = e^{2\pi i b (x-a)}f(x-a)$ .

Second, let $y(x) = f(x-a)$ . Then

$E_bf(x-a) = E_by(x) = e^{2\pi i b x}y(x) = e^{2\pi i b x}f(x-a)$ .

The two answers are not the same. Is there a problem with the notation, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: $E_b f(x-a)$ would be the function $E_b f$ evaluated at $x-a$, that is $e^{2 \pi i b (x-a)} f(x-a)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copper.hat is correct, but let me explain further.  The two answers you provided could be written as
$$ (E_b f)(x-a) \tag 1 $$
$$ E_b(f(x-a)) \tag 2 $$
However if you think about it, (2) makes no sense.  This is because $E_b$ is a function on $L^2(\mathbb R)$, whereas formula (2) is trying to apply $E_b$ to the scalar $f(x-a)$.

Some correct ways to write what you intended with your second answer could be
$$ (E_b(x\mapsto f(x-a)))(x) $$
or perhaps better (to avoid the letter $x$ being used in two different contexts)
$$ (E_b(z\mapsto f(z-a)))(x) $$
or a shorthand that is commonly used:
$$ (E_b(f(\cdot-a)))(x) $$
Anyway these are all rather messy.  Also I added an unnecessary set of brackets in these three expressions - for example, the last formula could be written as
$$ E_b(f(\cdot-a))(x) $$
because the other ordering of operations $E_b((f(\cdot-a))(x))$ again makes no sense because then $E_b$ is being applied to a scalar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which I think allows me to identify a potential source of confusion: in the definition of $E_b$, the symbol “$f(x)$” means something different on either side of the equation. On the right it means the scalar value of $f$ at the point $x$, while on the left it doesn't mean anything by itself because the "$f$" is only a fragment of the name of the function $E_b f$ which is being evaluated at the point $x$, i.e. $(E_b f)(x)$.

I now realize that this was unclear in my own mind because I had watched a lecturer using the symbol $E_bf(x-a)$ to represent $(E_b(f(.-a)))(x)$.

Comment: Thank you.  If you like my answer, you can reward me by pressing the green check mark against my answer.  That will give me 15 points, or something like that.  Thanks.